# Sorting a Dictionary with multiple Key:values pairs in the original key:value pair

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
bank_accts={accno:{"Name":"<str>","Balance":<num>}, repeat}.
```

I need to run a function where the user can view all of the accounts either by sorting by account number (accno), name, or balance.

I have an if, elif, else statement and I have the sort by accno working. I can't seem to be able to sort by Name or Balance. I have seen some complicated code but couldn't get it to work the way I need. So I decided to try to make all the "Name" values get put into a list, which I could then sort; however, the problem is each value gets put into a separate list with each character separated.

Any help is deeply appreciated. I am very new and am in a boot camp for learning python in a couple weeks. The instructor is more of a Google the answer, so I am trying to learn as I go. Thanks!

```
#This function will show all the bank accounts
def view_all_accts():
    sort=input("How would you like to sort? Please choose by account, name, or balance. ")
    if sort.lower() == "account":
        for acct in sorted(bank_acct.keys()):
            print("Account: %s" %(acct))
            for key in bank_acct[acct]:
                print(key +":"+str(bank_acct[acct][key]))
    elif sort.lower() == "name":
        for acct in bank_acct.keys():
            name=bank_acct[acct]["Name"]
            #gives every value of "Name"
            print(name)
            #will make every value into own list with each char separated
            temp=list(name)
            print(temp)
    #elif sort.lower()=="balance":
    else:
        print("Please choose account, name, or balance!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the `key` parameter to the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) function; this will allow us to use any key in a data structure we want as the comparison value for sorting.

Another thing you want to do is to effectively split the program in three more or less separate parts:

1. Get user input
2. Make a sorted data structure
3. Print out this data structure.

If you don't do this, you end up repeating yourself. In your example you're doing looping over and printing out `bank_acct` in two places − now what if you want to change something later? You'd have to change it in two places ;-)

Here's a full example with commented added:

```
bank_accts = {
    '456': {"Name":"LaVey","Balance":666},
    '123': {"Name":"Adams","Balance":42},
    '999': {"Name":"Zelany","Balance":64},
}

def view_all_accts():
    #########################
    ### 1. Get user input ###
    #########################
    # Get input, lowercase it
    sort = input("How would you like to sort? Please choose by account, name, or balance. ").lower()

    # Check if this is a valid key 
    valid_keys = ['account', 'name', 'balance']
    if sort not in valid_keys:
        print("Please choose account, name, or balance!")

        # Ask for input again
        return view_all_accts()

    #######################################
    ### 2. Make a sorted data structure ###
    #######################################
    # The key name (account) is a special case, so handle that first
    if sort == 'account':
        sorted_list = sorted(bank_accts.items())
    # Sort by one of the values
    else:
        # Capitalize the first letter of the sort key
        sort_key = sort.capitalize()

        # Now we can use the key= parameter for sorted()
        sorted_list = sorted(bank_accts.items(), key=lambda v: v[1][sort_key])

    #########################################
    ### 3. Print out this data structure. ###
    #########################################
    for account, data in sorted_list:
        print("Account: %s" % account)
        for k, v in data.items():
            print("  %s: %s" % (k, v))

view_all_accts()
```

Notice how this function is now separated in three independent parts − parts that you can now move to their own functions.

Comment: Thanks for this! I understand what you are doing, which is wonderful! There was a slight error, in case anyone else uses this, in which in part 2., the if sort = = 'account': it should be sorted_dict=sorted(bank_acct.items()). Also, don't forget to add the sorted_dict={} before starting anything. In addition, this does restrict the formatting to be the same for all 3 searches, which may or may not be wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tigger Oops, I tested the code, copied it to the answer, and changed some minor details & added the comments. I forgot to test it after that >_< I don't think you need a `sorted_dict={}` anywhere though? First off, it's a list not a dict (yeah, the name is silly, I changed it to `sorted_list`), but more importantly, it's always set...

Answer (score 0):

Your primary dictionary has accno as key.
Create 2 index dictionaries, having name and balance as keys and accno as elements of a value list. (Since a name or balance can occur multiple times)

With each insert in the prim dict, also insert in the index dicts under the right key.

With each delete from the prim. dict., also delete from the index dicts using name and balance as keys. As the list for a name or balance gets empty, delete the whole element of the index.

You can now simply sort the keys from each dict. This is (normal) "database indexing".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input! I like carpetsmoker's answer. I did come up with the below solution on my own as well, and would repeat that elif statement for my other value "Balance":

```
elif sort.lower() == "name":
        temp=[]
        for acct in bank_acct.keys():
            temp.append(bank_acct[acct]["Name"])
        #print(temp)
            temp.sort()
        #print(temp)
        for name in temp:
            for acct in bank_acct.keys():
                if name==bank_acct[acct]["Name"]:
                    print("Name: %s, Balance: $%d, Account #%s" %(bank_acct[acct]["Name"],bank_acct[acct]["Balance"],acct))
```